# How to solve custom loss error in tensoflow?

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow2.0

I am currently designing simple object detector using tensorflow,but I am facing to custom loss problems. And current dev environment is windows 10 native, and tensorflow-gpu=2.10.1.

```
def calc_iou_2D(set1: np.array, set2: np.array):

    assert len(set1.shape) == len(set2.shape) == 2

    SMOOTH = tf.cast(tf.constant(1e-6), dtype=tf.float32)
    iou_2D = []
    tf.print('11111111111111111111111')
    for item in set1:
        
        tf.print('item', item)
        tf.print('2222222222222222222222222222')
        x0_inter = tf.math.maximum(item[0], set2[:,0])
        y0_inter = tf.math.maximum(item[1], set2[:,1])
        x1_inter = tf.math.minimum(item[2], set2[:,2])
        y1_inter = tf.math.minimum(item[3], set2[:,3])

        intersection = tf.clip_by_value((x1_inter - x0_inter), 0, 1) * tf.clip_by_value((y1_inter - y0_inter), 0, 1)

        area_A = (item[2] - item[0]) * (item[3] - item[1])
        area_B = (set2[:,2] - set2[:,0]) * (set2[:,3] - set2[:,1])
        union = area_A + area_B - intersection
        tf.print('333333333333333333333')

        iou = (intersection + SMOOTH) / (union + SMOOTH)
        tf.print('44444444444444444444444')
        iou_2D.append((iou))
        tf.print('5555555555555555555555')

    return tf.transpose(tf.convert_to_tensor(iou_2D))


def test(dataset, anchor_boxes_xy):
    gt_boxes = np.array([[0.264     , 0.30960854, 0.392     , 0.4341637 ],
                   [0.206     , 0.27402135, 0.748     , 0.64768683],
                   [0.05      , 0.66903915, 0.086     , 0.84341637],
                   [0.388     , 0.63701068, 0.424     , 0.8113879 ]])
    gt_boxes = tf.convert_to_tensor(gt_boxes.astype('float32'))

    iou = calc_iou_2D(gt_boxes, anchor_boxes_xy)
    value, index = argmax(iou, axis=0)

class ssd_loss(tf.keras.losses.Loss):

    def __init__(self, anchorboxes_xy, name="ssd_loss"):
        super(ssd_loss, self).__init__(name=name)
        self.anchorboxes_xy = tf.convert_to_tensor(np.float32(anchorboxes_xy))
    
    def call(self, y_true, y_pred):
        y_true_cls_batch, y_true_boxes_batch = y_true[:, :, :1], y_true[:, :, 1:]
        y_pred_cls_batch, y_pred_boxes_batch = y_pred[:, :, :param['n_classes']], y_pred[:, :, param['n_classes']:]

        for i in range(param['batch_size']):
            iou = calc_iou_2D(y_true_boxes_batch[i], self.anchorboxes_xy)
            value, index = argmax(iou, axis=0)
            tf.print('value', value)
        
        loss_cls = tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy()(y_true_cls_batch, y_pred_cls_batch)
        loss_box = tf.keras.losses.MeanSquaredError()(y_true_boxes_batch, y_pred_boxes_batch)

        return loss_cls + loss_box
```

calc_iou_2D is working well inside test function but it does not work in ssd_loss function as follows

```
H = model.fit(train_ds, batch_size = param['batch_size'], epochs = param['epochs'], verbose=1)
(Pdb) n
11111111111111111111111
item [0.206 0.274021357 0.748 0.647686839]
2222222222222222222222222222
333333333333333333333  
44444444444444444444444
5555555555555555555555 
item [0.264 0.309608549 0.392 0.43416369]
2222222222222222222222222222
333333333333333333333
44444444444444444444444
5555555555555555555555
item [0.388 0.637010694 0.424 0.811387897]
2222222222222222222222222222
333333333333333333333
44444444444444444444444
5555555555555555555555
item [0.05 0.66903913 0.086 0.843416393]
2222222222222222222222222222
333333333333333333333
44444444444444444444444
5555555555555555555555
11111111111111111111111
item [0.355967075 0.2 0.716049373 0.7]
2222222222222222222222222222
333333333333333333333
44444444444444444444444
5555555555555555555555
11111111111111111111111
item [0.016 0.289617479 0.996 0.715847]
2222222222222222222222222222
333333333333333333333
44444444444444444444444
5555555555555555555555
item [0.84 0.543715835 0.962 0.614754081]
2222222222222222222222222222
333333333333333333333
44444444444444444444444
5555555555555555555555
item [0.648 0.510929 0.82 0.606557369]
2222222222222222222222222222
333333333333333333333
44444444444444444444444
5555555555555555555555
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InaccessibleTensorError: in user code:

    File "C:\Users\S-WONJU\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py", line 1160, in train_function  *
        return step_function(self, iterator)
    File "H:\object_detection\SSD\my_ssd\basic_OD_1.py", line 532, in call  *
        iou = calc_iou_2D(y_true_boxes_batch[i], self.anchorboxes_xy)
    File "H:\object_detection\SSD\my_ssd\basic_OD_1.py", line 142, in calc_iou_2D  *
        return tf.transpose(tf.convert_to_tensor(iou_2D))

    InaccessibleTensorError: <tf.Tensor 'ssd_loss/while/truediv:0' shape=(49,) dtype=float32> is out of scope and cannot be used here. Use return values, explicit Python locals or TensorFlow collections to access it.
    Please see https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/function#all_outputs_of_a_tffunction_must_be_return_values for more information.  

    <tf.Tensor 'ssd_loss/while/truediv:0' shape=(49,) dtype=float32> was defined here:
        File "H:\object_detection\SSD\my_ssd\basic_OD_1.py", line 817, in <module>
          train()
        File "H:\object_detection\SSD\my_ssd\basic_OD_1.py", line 622, in train
          H = model.fit(train_ds, batch_size = param['batch_size'], epochs = param['epochs'], verbose=1)
        File "C:\Users\S-WONJU\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\keras\utils\traceback_utils.py", line 65, in error_handler
          return fn(*args, **kwargs)
        File "C:\Users\S-WONJU\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py", line 1564, in 
fit
          tmp_logs = self.train_function(iterator)
        File "C:\Users\S-WONJU\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py", line 1160, in 
train_function
          return step_function(self, iterator)
        File "C:\Users\S-WONJU\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py", line 1146, in 
step_function
          outputs = model.distribute_strategy.run(run_step, args=(data,))
        File "C:\Users\S-WONJU\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py", line 1135, in 
run_step
          outputs = model.train_step(data)
        File "C:\Users\S-WONJU\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py", line 994, in train_step
          loss = self.compute_loss(x, y, y_pred, sample_weight)
        File "C:\Users\S-WONJU\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py", line 1052, in 
compute_loss
          return self.compiled_loss(
        File "C:\Users\S-WONJU\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\compile_utils.py", line 265, in __call__
          loss_value = loss_obj(y_t, y_p, sample_weight=sw)
        File "C:\Users\S-WONJU\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\keras\losses.py", line 152, in __call__  
          losses = call_fn(y_true, y_pred)
        File "H:\object_detection\SSD\my_ssd\basic_OD_1.py", line 531, in call
          for i in range(param['batch_size']):
        File "H:\object_detection\SSD\my_ssd\basic_OD_1.py", line 532, in call
          iou = calc_iou_2D(y_true_boxes_batch[i], self.anchorboxes_xy)
        File "H:\object_detection\SSD\my_ssd\basic_OD_1.py", line 119, in calc_iou_2D
          for item in set1:
        File "H:\object_detection\SSD\my_ssd\basic_OD_1.py", line 137, in calc_iou_2D
          iou = (intersection + SMOOTH) / (union + SMOOTH)

    The tensor <tf.Tensor 'ssd_loss/while/truediv:0' shape=(49,) dtype=float32> cannot be accessed from FuncGraph(name=train_function, id=2585060633536), because it was defined in FuncGraph(name=ssd_loss_while_body_3411, id=2585079461824), which is out of scope.
> h:\object_detection\ssd\my_ssd\basic_od_1.py(622)train()
-> H = model.fit(train_ds, batch_size = param['batch_size'], epochs = param['epochs'], verbose=1)
```

Based on print results, first batch data is well used, but i guess second batch is not accessible.

I just want to run calc_iou_2D inside the loss function. I don't know how to solve this problem, please help me.